# How can We download files(apiDefinition.swagger.json,apiProperties.json,settings.json) from Logic Apps Custom Connector using CLI tool?

Tags: azure-logic-apps

I go through the below MSDN link to certify custom connector, In that link in the "Step 4: Prepare the connector artifacts" it is given to download files from connector for Power Platform.
As we created Logic Apps Custom Connectors, there is no way mentioned to download files from it.

**Link :** https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/custom-connectors/certification-submission#step-4-prepare-the-connector-artifacts

So does anyone help me out how to download files from Logic Apps Custom connector instead of Power Platform?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Azure CLI instead and follow the same process.

- Before running `paconn login` try installing paconn `pip install paconn` and then you 'll be directed to sign in using Microsoft's Device Code process.
- Then download your custom connector files using `paconn download` whenafter you've been authenticated.

[image]

Comment: Thanks SwethaKandikonda-MT for reply.
I followed the same steps but it is for Power Platform not for Logic Apps.
In first steps it asking for Select an Environment, and in listing of environment no other environment other than default. So I selected 1 as choice and then asking to select connector but as I have created Logic App custom connector it is not displayed in list for selection. So how can we download files from Logic Apps Custom connector using paconn command?